# Cannot PUT/GET objects in MinIO (MacOS)

Tags: docker-compose, presto, minio

Thank you for reading!

We are running Presto along with Minio using `docker-compose`:

```
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:RELEASE.2021-08-31T05-46-54Z
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - 9094:9000
      - 9001:9001
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio123
      MINIO_REGION: us-east-1
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    mem_limit: 512m

  presto:
    image: ahanaio/prestodb-sandbox:0.250
    container_name: presto
    ports:
      - 9095:8080
    volumes: 
      - ./presto/minio.properties:/opt/presto-server/etc/catalog/minio.properties
      - ./presto/create-table.sql:/opt/create-table.sql
      - ./presto/sync-partitions.sql:/opt/sync-partitions.sql
    mem_limit: 1024m
```

We upload a bunch of data to minio, and then create a subdirectory with the following Presto SQL:

```
use minio.default;

CREATE TABLE orders ( 
  "name" array(varchar)
  "year" int, 
  "month" tinyint, 
  "day" tinyint) 
WITH (
  format='JSON', 
  external_location='s3a://orders-local/json/',
  partitioned_by=ARRAY['year', 'month', 'day']
  );
```

After executing the SQL statement, developers on our team are seeing inconsistent results in the `orders-local` bucket. In some cases, the `json` directory is present. In others, it is not present.

We are all running the same docker containers. So far, we are only seeing the issue on *some* MacOS instances, but not all. We have also ruled out OS version as we see successes and failures in Big Sur as well as Catalina.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of inconsistency?

Comment: Do you want to see if Trino has the same issue for you? I never had this issue running with Trino. https://github.com/bitsondatadev/trino-getting-started/tree/main/hive/trino-minio

Comment: If you're not familiar with the project, it is the project driven by the creators and majority code contributors of Presto and is, for all intents and purposes, an upgrade. https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html

Comment: We have a workaround for this. SSH into the hadoop container and execute the following commands:
`hdfs dfs -mkdir s3a://orders-local/json/`
`hdfs dfs -touchz s3a://orders-local/json/test.txt`
This manually creates the subdirectory, and places a dummy file in it. This guarantees that presto will see this subdirectory properly.

Comment: Uff sorry you have to run that hack just to get this working. Seems like you may be stuck on Presto for now? Let me know if you want to make the hop over to Trino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our environment variables are being overwritten by values in `~/.aws`

We can't resolve why the env vars are not being honored, but we know this line is the culprit:

`config.WithDefaultRegion(os.Getenv("STORAGE_REGION"))`

We successfully get the right region with the os.Getenv() call, however config still pulls the value from our $HOME/.aws/config file.

So it seems that the presence of a `.aws/config` file takes precedence over the environment variables.